# How to replace characters within a substring with sed or awk?

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I need to replace special characters from some file names (and only file names) in an HTML document. I know how to replace special characters in the *whole* text with `tr` or `sed`, I know how to replace the file name with another given string with `sed` (e.g. `'s,src="\([^"]*\)",src="newprefixtofilename_\1"'`), but I am not sure `sed` can in some way match characters inside what I get in `\1`?

If `sed` is not able to do this, how can I do it e.g. with `awk`? It is probably possible to isolate the `"` delimited strings that are prefixed with `src=` and go a `gsub` on these only. I can assume that `src=` appears only in  tags (so no "real" html parsing) and that there is only one string to match per file line.

Example input line:

```
  <img src="spécial.png"> Spécial
  <img src="piètre.png"> Some text including "piètre"
```

Desired output with `[éî]` replaced by `[ei]` only in filenames:

```
 <img src="special.png"> Spécial
 <img src="pietre.png"> Some text including "piètre"
```

Comment: Neither sed nor awk was designed for parsing HTML. First, find a proper tool

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and the desired output?

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for your comment, however this is 1 line in a script which is better done in bash.

Comment: why not `sed 's,src="spécial.png",src="special.png",'` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Because I have all sorts of very different file names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do this with `sed` directly (don't know about awk, tho). First you need to create a secondary file in which you replace every character for an UTF8 character, than parse and replace the differences.

I will strongly suggest to try it on test data first.

```
# Translate non UTF8
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit files.html > tmp.txt

# Create arrays (IFS if files have spaces, otherwise redundant)
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ FROM=($(diff files.html tmp.txt | grep '^<.*<img' | sed -r 's/.*src="([^"]*)".*/\1/'))
$ TO=($(diff files.html tmp.txt | grep '^>.*<img' | sed -r 's/.*src="([^"]*)".*/\1/'))

# Rename files (mv spécial.png special.png)
$ for ((i=0; i < ${#FROM[@]}; i++)); do mv "${FROM[$i]}" "${TO[$i]}"; done

# Change html src attributes
$ for ((i=0; i < ${#FROM[@]}; i++)); do sed -i "s/${FROM[$i]}/${TO[$i]}/" files.html; done

# End result
$ cat files.html 
<img src="special.png"> Spécial
<img src="pietre.png"> Some text including "piètre"
```

Comment: Thanks Bayou, this is clever and seems actually pretty robust. Why the '>' and '<' in the `grep` of "Create arrays" part?

Comment: You're welcome. By grepping `>` or `<`, you filter out differences in one file relative to the other. Thus, `grep <` gives the difference in files.html and `grep >` for those in tmp.txt. If you have files with a space in it, use `IFS=$'\n'` before you create the arrays.

Comment: Tested and approved.

Answer (score 1):

Stating the requirement: replace special character ( é->e, î->i), only inside src="..." tokens.

Assuming the XML files are formatted reasonable (more specific, the full IMG tag is on one line), can be achieved replacing each of the special characters using 's' command.

```
First line é->e, second line î->i
sed -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)é\([^"]*"\),src=\1e\2,g' \
    -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)î\([^"]*"\),src=\1i\2,g'
```

The above solution will not handle src that has the same special characters more than once.  (e.g., src-"xîzîtîFi.png". If this is an issue, and assuming small number of repeats is accepted 92 in below example, then

```
   # é->e 
sed -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)é\([^"]*"\),src="\1e\2,g' \
  -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)é\([^"]*"\),src="\1e\2,g' \
  -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)é\([^"]*"\),src="\1e\2,g' \
  -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)î\([^"]*"\),src="\1i\2,g' \
  -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)î\([^"]*"\),src="\1i\2,g' \
  -e 's,src="\([^"]*\)î\([^"]*"\),src="\1i\2,g'
```

I'm sure that there is a possibility to using labels/branch to perform above substitution more beneficently to handle unlimited number of special characters.

**Renaming files**
The other question can leverage 'sed' Transliterate command. Something like:

```
for file in FILELIST ; do
  new_name=$(echo $file | sed -e 'y/éî/ei/')
  if [ "$file" != "$new_name] ; then
    mv $file $new_name
  if
done
```

Comment: `more than once` - you _can_ loop until replacement happens with `t`. Basically you do `: loop; /src="\([^"]*\)é\([^"]*"\)/{ s//src="\1e\2/g; t end; b loop; } : end;`